# I purchased a used SSD. What should I do with it before using it to check that it's healthy, hasn't been "abused", and isn't counterfeit?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, security

As per the title I purchased a "used" SSD.

I've read about cases where users have purchased used drives and discovered they are somehow unhealthy or have been abused or tampered with somehow, for example:

- The returned drive has been replaced with a fake one and can't be filled to its advertised capacity
- The used drive has been used extensively (i.e. has billions of write cycles)
- Some of the SMART flags are failing on the drive

What tests should I use to verify that the used drive I've bought has not fallen foul of any of these or similar pitfalls?

Comment: Run this utility on it>>>>>https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Any. Linux, Mac, or Windows. Whatever :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to running CrystalDiskInfo to check the SMART status as @Moab commented, also run the manufacturer's utility to check health and if it has an option to run a long self-test, you can do that too.

You should do a full format (so every sector gets written to to help ferret out any bad sectors).  Check health again per the above note after running this.  You may want to take note of the total bad blocks before and after you do this to get a sense of if it seems like they went up a lot.  Please note that there's one metric which is how many bad blocks the drive came from the factory with (and they marked it not to use them for data) which is not a concern, and there's another which is how many developed later on (which is what's of concern).

If you're extra paranoid, you could see if there's a firmware update you can apply to the drive on the off chance it has malware at the firmware level (I think this is probably very unlikely).  Even if this isn't the case, it could still provide bug fixes and is safer to do when you have no data you care about on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or macOS you can determine drive capacity by simply writing a huge file to the drive and then checking that file’s size.

I use this simple method to effectively “wipe” drives I sell or send to e-junk places:

```
cat /dev/zero >> /Volume/DriveName/zero_test.txt
```

That command endlessly streams zeros to the file `/Volume/DriveName/zero_test.txt`.

Let it run until it exits due to the device being full and then run this command to see how large that file is:

```
ls -lah /Volume/DriveName/zero_test.txt
```

The size of that `/Volume/DriveName/zero_test.txt` file should come close to the true capacity of the drive.

And when done, just run this command to delete the file and you are good to go:

```
rm /Volume/DriveName/zero_test.txt
```